# Where FacesMessage FacesContext in Thorntail 2.3?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, thorntail

I'm developing test task, with stack: thorntail 2.3.0.Final, PrimeFaces 6.2.

There is example:

```
public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Car Edited", ((Car) event.getObject()).getId());
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}
```

But I can't import `FacesMessage` and `FacesContext`, my IDE can't find them in all dependencies

A bit of my pom.xml thorntail with bom:

```
…
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
        <artifactId>jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
…
```

So, what's going on? It's jsf 2.3 with some new approaches to this packages or something else?

I've read about jsf 2.3 that it has new features and some deprecations.

Also where `@ViewScoped`? What now we should use with CDI?

Where package for `import javax.faces.*`?

I'm confused…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug in that https://github.com/thorntail/thorntail/blob/master/fractions/javaee/jsf/pom.xml doesn't add the JSF APIs as dependencies available to your application.

An easy fix is to add the JSF APIs as "provided" in your project, as at runtime they will be used fine.

Comment: @Ken added with scope provided, no luck. Stacktrace error. Also I created an [issue](https://github.com/thorntail/thorntail/issues/1226), for now can't mark answer as resolved

Comment: Ken is right, it's a bug. I filed https://issues.jboss.org/browse/THORN-2327, as GitHub issues are not used for Thorntail v2, only for  v4. As for the workaround, what coordinates did you use? I did a little experiment and adding `org.jboss.spec.javax.faces:jboss-jsf-api_2.3_spec:2.3.5.SP1` with `<scope>provided</scope>` did help.

Comment: @Ken @Ladicek sorry, my fault, in pom `io.thorntail:jsf`somehow I inserted `<scope>provided</scope>` so after that any additional dependancies which implement jsf realisation not started. So the answer is correct! just add some realisation, it doesn't matter what, I added `javax.faces:javax.faces-api:2.3`and it starts good!